# Error with the procedure written to Back up and restore the DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written the below SP and getting below error. Could  any one please help me finding the error.

```
create procedure CopyDB(@DBName varchar(100),@Newname varchar(100))
as
DECLARE @FileName AS nvarchar(4000)
set @FileName = 'D:\'+@DBName+'.bak'
/*Backup the database*/
BACKUP DATABASE @DBName
TO DISK = @FileName
WITH CHECKSUM, INIT;
/*to restore it with new name*/
RESTORE database @Newname
FROM DISK = @FileName
with 
MOVE @DBName TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\'+@Newname+'.mdf',
MOVE @DBName TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\'+@Newname+'_log.LDF',
CHECKSUM;
```

Error message is :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CopyDB, Line 13 Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CopyDB(@DBName varchar(100),@Newname varchar(100))
as
DECLARE @FileName AS nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @varPathMdf varchar(200),@varPathLdf varchar(200)
SET @varPathMdf='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\'+@Newname+'.mdf'
SET @varPathLdf='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\'+@Newname+'_log.LDF'
SET @FileName = 'D:\'+@DBName+'.bak'
/*Backup the database*/
BACKUP DATABASE @DBName
TO DISK = @FileName
WITH CHECKSUM, INIT;
/*to restore it with new name*/
RESTORE database @Newname
FROM DISK = @FileName
with 
MOVE @DBName TO @varPathMdf,
MOVE @DBName TO @varPathLdf,
CHECKSUM;
```

Autogenerated Script for restoring of my database:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [1] FILE = N'Analytics_Data' 
FROM  DISK = N'E:\DatabaseBackups\analytics.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'Analytics_Data' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\1.mdf',  
MOVE N'Analytics_Log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\1_0.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

You can see that @DBName in my case have _Data or _Log in the end. I think you need to do te same or generate the script automatically.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have got the following error. Processed 168 pages for database 'Amrutha', file 'Amrutha' on file 1. Processed 1 pages for database 'Amrutha', file 'Amrutha_log' on file 1. BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 169 pages in 0.213 seconds (6.198 MB/sec). Msg 4353, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CDB, Line 15 Conflicting file relocations have been specified for file 'Amrutha'. Only a single WITH MOVE clause should be specified for any logical file name. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CDB, Line 15 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: I edited the answer. I think you'd better generate the script automatically.

Comment: :- How can i generate automatically. could u please give me an idea to do it.

Comment: I have to perform this task within a another stored procedure. so, I tought of writing stored procedure.

Comment: I ment that when you generate the script you will be able to write SP using it as example. I edited the answer. Now there are print screens of how to generate the script

Answer (score 3):

The error in your script is in the `MOVE` clause.
You have to use the logical names of your database files (one `MOVE` for each logical name) instead of `@DBName` every time.

You can get the logical file names by running the following query on your database:

```
select name, filename from sysfiles
```

`name` is the logical name of the database file.
`filename` is where it's on the disk right now.

By default, SQL Server databases have only two database files (the database and the log), but there can be more (the database can be split in several files).
The logical names are often like this:

- `DatabaseName` or `DatabaseName_Data` for the database file
- `DatabaseName_Log` for the log file

...but unfortunately you can't rely on that, because you can give the files any name you want.

If you really want to script this in a general way and you have more than one database, it's the easiest way to make sure that all databases have the same number of database files and that the logical names all match the same pattern (like `DatabaseName_Data` and `DatabaseName_Log`, for example).
If you don't do this, you have to get the number of database files and their logical names on the fly, which will make the SP much more complex.